# Removing trailing comma from all iterations

Tags: c++

I am aware on how to remove trailing commas, but I cannot seem to figure out how to remove trailing commas from all the iterations as my code only removes the last one. The output I get is the following when calling this method multiple times:

```
A:on 0 -> B, on 1 -> A, 
B:on 0 -> C, on 1 -> A, 
C:on 0 -> C, on 1 -> A
```

---

```
string FSA::transitions_to_string(string s) {

    std::ostringstream oss;
    string output = "";
    map<string, string>::iterator itr1;
    map<string, map<string, string> >::iterator itr2;
    map<string, map<string, string> >::iterator itr3;

    itr3 = table_.find(s);

    if (itr3 == table_.end()) {
        throw domain_error (s + " doesn't exist");
    }

   for (itr2 = table_.begin(); itr2 != table_.end(); itr2++) {
    oss << itr2->first << ":";
        for (itr1 = itr2->second.begin(); itr1 != itr2->second.end(); itr1++) {
            oss << "on " << itr1->first << " -> " << itr1->second << ", ";
            output = oss.str();
        }

    oss << endl;
    }

    return output.substr(0, output.size() - 2);
}
```

Comment: You're the one writing the comma, so you don't need to "remove" it; just _don't write it in the first place_.

Comment: I wonder whether you even know what this code does? And how it works? Did you write it yourself?

Comment: I just want to remove the last trailing comma so the output actually is:

`A:on 0 -> B, on 1 -> A 
B:on 0 -> C, on 1 -> A 
C:on 0 -> C, on 1 -> A`

Comment: @BoundaryImposition It keeps overwriting `output`, but that doesn't matter (other than performance-wise) because `oss` continues to grow.

Comment: @interjay: Oh, true.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than remove the trailing comma, as @BoundaryImposition notes, you can just *not write it*

```
for (itr2 = table_.begin(); itr2 != table_.end(); itr2++) {
    string delim = ""; // set blank for first element of each inner loop
    oss << itr2->first << ":";
    for (itr1 = itr2->second.begin(); itr1 != itr2->second.end(); itr1++) {
        oss << delim << "on " << itr1->first << " -> " << itr1->second;
        delim = ", "; // after first loop this is a nop
    }
    oss << endl;
}
return oss.str();
```